# MySQL fulltext search: how to find out in which column the search query has been found?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

This is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
          MATCH(textEN,textDE,textPT,titlePT,titleDE,titleEN) AGAINST('$search') AS score
          FROM $main_db.ff_pages
        WHERE MATCH(textEN,textDE,textPT,titlePT,titleDE,titleEN) AGAINST('$search')
        ORDER BY score DESC";
```

Everything works fine. As you can see I have a multi-langage website, and that's why I need to know in which of the columns the searched expression has been found. For example, i would like to know that the expression "Solar system" has been found in the column "textEN", in order to display the english version of the site in the search results.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What if there are multiple matches?

Comment: then i would like to know it for each of the matches...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to perform [`MATCH() ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) for each column separately (although one advantage of this is that you can quantify the contribution each column made to the overall score).

Taking maximum advantage of the additive nature of MySQL's relevance scores and its cacheing of deterministic functions, I would do:

```
SELECT   *,
         MATCH(textEN)  AGAINST('$search') AS score_textEN,
         MATCH(textDE)  AGAINST('$search') AS score_textDE,
         MATCH(textPT)  AGAINST('$search') AS score_textPT,
         MATCH(titleEN) AGAINST('$search') AS score_titleEN,
         MATCH(titleDE) AGAINST('$search') AS score_titleDE,
         MATCH(titlePT) AGAINST('$search') AS score_titlePT,
FROM     $main_db.ff_pages
WHERE    MATCH(textEN)  AGAINST('$search')
      OR MATCH(textDE)  AGAINST('$search')
      OR MATCH(textPT)  AGAINST('$search')
      OR MATCH(titleEN) AGAINST('$search')
      OR MATCH(titleDE) AGAINST('$search')
      OR MATCH(titlePT) AGAINST('$search')
ORDER BY score_textEN  + score_textDE  + score_textPT
         score_titleEN + score_titleDE + score_titlePT DESC
```